# Magento 1: What is the function "$invoice->register()" for?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, invoice, create-invoice

I try to generate invoices programmatically in Magento 1.9.4. It works so far with this code:

```
    $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
    if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
      Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
    }
    $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);      
    // $invoice->register();

    $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
        ->addObject($invoice)
        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

    $transaction->save();
```

As you can see, I commented out $invoice->register() as it produces an error while executed (at least, with a specific payment option):
Can anyone explain, what $invoice->register() actually is for?